# multi-line selection in sublime text 2

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2, selection

I want to select the text in all the `alt tag` and type in some identical text. I could be using the wrong key combinations.  I've tried several combinations:

- `alt+left-click` hold and drag the mouse,
- `ctrl+left-click` hold and drag the mouse,
- `ctrl+alt+left-click` hold and drag the mouse,
- `ctrl+alt+shift+left-click` hold and drag the mouse,
- `ctrl+shift+L+left-click` drag the mouse,

as well as swapping to "`right-click+`" with those combinations and here is the result:

[image]

That is **not** what I want.

The following is what I want to select:

[image]

In Sublime Text 2 using the MAC, you can hold down the `option` key and drag to make the selection.  So usually in Windows, that  means holding down the `alt` key.  Holding down the `alt` key does not work.  I checked out the key bindings in Sublime Text 2:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

If the up key is the arrow `up` key, this doesn't work either.  I've also tried `ctrl+shift+L` without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just kept trying and I stumbled upon the answer.  I was going to delete the question since it was soon after I posted that I got it, but thought I would post for anyone who may have the same issue and have tried everything else others have posted.

**Answer**:

1. Left-click to place your cursor in the area you want to make a
   multi-line selection, release left-click
2. After that selection, **hold down** the `ctrl` key
3. Left-click in the area you want to select in the line below *(in my case it was the `alt tag` text)*
4. Keep holding down the `ctrl` key, `left-click` each area
   **individually** -- **do not drag the mouse while holding `ctrl` key**.  *Dragging selects everything from the starting point, not the individual area you want*

Comment: But that's not really the solution for your problem right? Is it not possible to drag the mouse for multiple carrets?

Answer (score 8):

Try <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> + Drag or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> + Drag

Comment: O.O - I've been using Sublime Text for years. I love all its multiline selection features, and somehow I only just discovered this. I think I'm going to love this, too.